# How to create cloud portal and pages for it in Liferay 7.2 portal?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

A year ago, We had embedded the Dashboard in Liferay 6.2 portal easily as using the following link.

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/10328/publishing-dashboards-in-liferay

Now, we couldn't achieve the same in current the Liferay 7.2. Current UI is not same as old Liferay 6.2, it totally different from old UI.

I know, how to embed the dashboards in other application and portal. But don't know the ways to create cloud portal and go to Pages section on it.

How to create cloud portal easily and go to Pages section to achieve my embedding part?

Comment: Hi vinothtechie,

Can you give more detail about the problem you are having? Instructions are very straightforward.

I have reviewed the instructions in https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/10328/publishing-dashboards-in-liferay and they are fine for 7.1 version
In 7.2 versions, the steps are more or less the same, but "Build" menu has been renamed to "Site Building".

So in order to create the Embedded page go to: Open your site => Site Builder menu => Pages => click add [+] button =>  click on "Embedded" option. Configure page name and once page was created, set the external URL.

Comment: Hi @jorgediaz-lr, Thnks for your response. I don't know about site creation in updated Liferay 7.2 UI.  I don't have idea, where to start for site creation and Site Builder menu. Can you share steps or guidelines to create site in Liferay site. Then I would can check your Site Building steps.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - the way the question is currently phrased is not a good fit for stackoverflow